# Segue between view controllers not functioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have an app that allows the user to take a picture, and when the picture is taken (push action) should then navigate to another view controller to allow the user to discard, edit, or save the photo. I try to segue from the camera view controller in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method, like so:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

        // Save the new image to camera roll (will change later)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
        [self.capturedImages addObject: imageToSave];

        _imageView.image = [self imageToSave:imageToSave];
    }


CaptureViewController *capture = [[CaptureViewController alloc] init];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"takePic" sender:self];
```

}

The didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method is called when a button is pressed, prompting `[_picker takePicture];` Here is my prepare for segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller

    //this is just a temporary fix
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takePic"]) {
        CaptureViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

The segue identifier is "takePic", so that's not the issue. That would be too simple. When I try to perform the segue, nothing happens. The camera still shows and the two buttons I have in the `imagePickerController's` `cameraOverlayView` are still there (although they are non-functional). Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you're dismissing the image picker controller. `UIImagePickerController` is [pretty picky](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) about how you present it. So, make sure that you're presenting it the way it expects to be presented. When the image is captured or selected, you also need to dismiss the image picker controller. Since you don't see it going away, I strongly suspect that you're not dismissing it anywhere.

Add a line like:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to your `... didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.